# Campo ingresado que baje y un nuevo campo vacio

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap

Hola tengo el siguiente código al momento de apretar el botón "Agregar +" se ingresa una fila nueva a la tabla para seguir ingresando datos. Mi pregunta es la siguiente hay alguna forma donde al apretar el botón "Agregar +" el campo que yo agregue baje con el botón al lado "Quitar" y un nuevo campo vació al lado del botón "Agregar +".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="es-es">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">

            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Postulación" class="form-control name_list" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar + </button>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg btn-block" value="Ingresar Postulaciones" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var i = 1;
            $('#add').click(function() {
                i++;
                $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Postulación" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">Quitar</button></td></tr>');
            });
            $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
                var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
                $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Espero poder explicarme bien. cualquier duda estaré mirando el post. Saludos

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que deseas

Comment: Dígito una postulacion pero deseo agregar otra mas, al apretar el boton "agregar +" la postulacion que digite baje y se inserte una campo vacio en la primera fila.

Comment: Lo que deseas es ir desplazando los input creados hacia arriba por asi decirlo, y los que estan creados vayan bajando o llendose al fondo?

Comment: los input creados hacia bajo como esta en el código pero que estos bajen con los datos que yo ingreso, para después ingresar todos de una.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo tienes que cambiar el append por after, asi: 
Solo tiene un pequeño detalle con el input que tenias al principio, porque el td y el tr no tienen id, por eso no se desplaza. Lo ideal es crear todos desde cero y alli funciona como quieres.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
            var i = 1;
            $('#add').click(function() {
                i++;
                $('#dynamic_field tr:first').after('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Postulación" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">Quitar</button></td></tr>');
            });
            $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
                var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
                $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
            });
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="es-es">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">

            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
                <tr id="row">
                    <td>
                        <input  type="hidden" name="name[]" placeholder="Postulación" class="form-control name_list" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar + </button>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg btn-block" value="Ingresar Postulaciones" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Algo así deseo muchas gracias mirare el código y veré que podre hacer.
Muchas gracias por tu tiempo :)

Comment: Cualquier duda por aquí estaremos